# T-SQL Code won't give desired output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT 
Counting = ISNULL(COUNT(A.Numbers), 0),
B.Date AS DateX
From Schema1.Table A INNER JOIN Schema2.Table B
ON A.xyz=B.xyz
Where B.Date = GetDate()
Group by B.Date
```

Sometimes, `B.Date` won’t have today’s date. I would still like to have result output with `Counting = 0 and DateX = Todays date`.

How would I do that?

Thank you

**EDIT** by popular demand

```
A.Numbers = 123;456;789;012,...etc
B.Date = 2012-11-24, 2012-11-24,-212-11-24,2012-11-26
```

So count for `2012-11-24 = 3` and `2012-11-26 = 1` but there would be no output when I set `B.Date` to `2012-11-25`
I want to show `Counting = 0` when `B.Date = 2012-11-25`

Comment: Your query currently looks for rows where `B.Date` = the current millisecond, which is unlikely to ever happen. Shouldn't you be searching for `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, B.Date) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` or `WHERE B.Date >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND B.Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`?

Comment: I have conversion put in place to just get YYYY-MM-DD...this was just a simpler version.

Comment: Any type of string conversion to strip time is going to make your where clause non-sargable. You should be using one of the methods I listed in my comment. Please see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime and http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of your where clause and change your select to

```
Counting = (Case when B.Date = GETDATE() then ISNULL(COUNT(A.Numbers),0) else 0 end)
```

Comment: When I use a valid date (date that has data), I get two rows, 1st row is 0 and 2nd row has valid count (# > 0)...how do I get rid of 0 when the date and count is "valid"?

Comment: @user1569220 Please show sample data and desired results. Impossible to determine what you're looking for if we can't see where it's coming from.

Comment: Got it...added TOP 1 and did ORDER BY Counting DESC